# Configuring an aiohttp app hosted by gunicorn

Tags: python-3.x, gunicorn, aiohttp

I implemented my first `aiohttp` based RESTlike service, which works quite fine as a toy example. Now I want to run it using `gunicorn`. All examples I found, specify some prepared application in some module, which is then hosted by `gunicorn`. This requires me to setup the application at import time, which I don't like. I would like to specify some config file (development.ini, production.ini) as I'm used from `Pyramid` and setup the application based on that ini file.

This is common to more or less all python web frameworks, but I don't get how to do it with aiohttp + gunicorn. What is the smartest way to switch between development and production settings using those tools?

Answer (score 1):

At least for now aiohttp is a library without reading configuration from `.ini` or `.yaml` file.

But you can write code for reading config and setting up aiohttp server by hands easy.